# Alternative to "goto" in PHP

Tags: php, loops, goto

my php server use PHP Version 5.2.17 and php goto dont work.

how to do this loop without "goto"??

```
while ($i <= $dadosrolados) {
    a:
    $j = rand(1,10);
    if (isset($um) and $j == 1) {
        goto a;
    }
    else {
        $dados["Dado ".$i] = "$j";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You could put the `$i++` inside the else, that seems like it would give you the same results

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Use `continue` as Dave suggest, and for the love of god, try to refrain from using a `goto`. Ever. [Seriously](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: @Dave That should be an answer, not a comment. It is precisely the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do {
  $j = rand(1,10);
} while (isset($um) and $j == 1);
```